# adding predicates to sentential logic

Tags: logic

What happens when I add **only** first-order predicates, a finite number of them, to propositional logic? I will not use quantifiers, recursion and relations. Under any interpretation, I can unambiguously evaluate the predicate to be true or false. Can I, in this setup, assume I am still working in the world of propositional logic? Have I changed anything substantial?

Comment: Without quantifiers, you have, for a predicate $P$, two cases: $P(x)$ and $P(c)$, where $x$ and $c$ are respectively a *variable* and a *constant*. The second one is simply a *sentence*, that is true or false, and thus add nothing to the sentential variables. The first one is different, because with it we have to enlarge the semantics, in order to have a way to assign "meaning" (and thus a truth value) to an *atom* with a free variable.

Comment: You can see e.g. [Chiswell & Hodges](https://books.google.it/books?id=JeUDUWYD5eQC&pg=PA101), **Ch.5 Quantifier-free logic** for the discussion of FOL logic fragment without quantifiers.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to amplify what Mauro says in his comments.

The vocabulary of a pure propositional logic has symbols for atomic propositions ('$P$', '$Q$', '$R$', etc.) plus connectives. There are then familiar rules for building molecular wffs of arbitrary complexity from this vocabulary, familiar definitions for logical relations between these wffs, familiar deductive systems for making inferences with them. And so on.

What happens if you add **only** some (first-order) predicates to the vocabulary of your logic?

Nothing. And for a trivial reason. That's because predicates by themselves do not allows us to form additional wffs (if that's all we have, we have no terms to combine them with to form wffs). There are no new propositions you can express with them. They will be entirely idle wheels cluttering up the vocabulary.

So you need also to add to your vocabularly at some terms (names and/or variables) to go along with the predicates to allow us to form new wffs.

If you add names, then you will now get some new wffs to play with (the likes of '$Fm$' '$Gn$' perhaps to put alongside '$P$', '$Q$'). But still nothing exciting is happening, as far as the logic goes. The added complexity doesn't really buy you anything. The only logical entailments will still be the tautological entailments. It's just that you now have more atomic propositions to build molecular ones out of. We can write things like '$Fm \land Gm \vDash Fm$', but the internal structure of  $Fm$,  $Gm$ is doing no work.

If you add variables, however, things can get much more interesting. For example you can form a wff like '$Fx \to Gx$' and *set things up so that this is interpreted as implicitly general*. Then we do get new implications that are no longer mere truth-functional tautological implications, like, for example, '$Fx \to Gx, Fm \vDash Gm$'. In effect, we get a fragment of quantificational logic. As Mauro helpfully notes, you can find more about this in Chiswell & Hodges's wonderful *Mathematical Logic*, Ch.5 Quantifier-free logic.